# Automatically open app on USB mount

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Whenever I plug in a USB device (e.g. my phone, or a sdcard) ubuntu pops up a window asking what application to open it with. You can choose to "always open in this application"

Where is that configuration stored and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of nautilus. `System` | `Preferences` | `File Management` | `Media`

Comment: I think I miss a package. However, I found it under "Edit » Configuration » Media" (My Ubuntu is Dutch, so the translation may not be 100% accurate). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you were accessing it from a nautilus window instead of the main menu then that's where you'd find it.